# Is there a nonHausdorff topology on $\mathbb{R}$ such that we still have the closedness/boundedness equivalence to compactness?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, real-numbers

Using the standard topology of $\mathbb{R}$ is sufficient to ensure that a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is closed and bounded and vice versa. A standard topology of $\mathbb{R}$ is Hausdorff. I wonder if there is a nonHausdorff topology on $\mathbb{R}$ such that with respect to which a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded.

Note:
Thanks to the contributors' works. I made a mistake. What I am after is a nonHausdorff topology $\tau$ on $\mathbb{R}$ such that, if $\tau'$ is the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$, a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is $\tau$-compact if and only if it is $\tau$-closed and $\tau'$-bounded. It is great to know the existence of that type of nonHausdorff topology ($\tau$-bounded) as given in an answer below too.

Comment: You ask tha compact implies closed and bounded or you ask for an if and only if?

Comment: @user126154, Hi, thanks. Yes, equivalence is after.

Comment: Do you mean compactness in the *new* topology is equivalent to closed and bounded in the *old* topology, or compactness in the *new* topology is equivalent to closed and bounded in the *new* topology?

Comment: @NoahSchweber, Hi, thanks. Yes, new topology for both.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, Hi, sorry. I made a mistake. You are right; I was after the equivalence such that compactness and closedness are relative to the nonHausdorff topology and the boundedness is relative to the usual topology! (thus cofinite example)

Answer (score 3):

Consider the equivalence relation generated by $x\sim y$ if they both are in $[0,1]$. Then let $\tau$ be the topology saturated by such relation (i.e. take the quotient space and then pull back the quotient topology). Explicitly, you declare a set open if it is open in Euclidean topology and if, whenever it contains a point in $[0,1]$ then it contains the whole $[0,1]$.

Such topology in not hausdorff because points in $[0, 1]$ are indistinguishable. But from the fact that the quotient space is homeo to $\mathbb R$ you get the desired property.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question, but if you think the answer is incorrect, please explain so that I can correct. Why downvote?

Comment: +1. Note that this is overkill: you could just fix distinct reals $x,y$ and consider the topology $\tau=\{X:$ $X$ is open in the usual topology and $x\in X\iff y\in X\}$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I thought it was easy to prove required properties by using that the quotient is R.

Comment: Thank you. The answer makes me wonder further that what if boundedness is required to be with respect to the usual topology (compactness and closedness are with respect to the new topology)? Is it possible to do that?

Comment: boundedness does not depend on the topology. It depends on the metric or on the order of R. Both induces the standard topology. But in general what does it mean "bounded" for a topology? Many mathematicians use "bounded" with the meaning: "contained in a compact. So the example give works with this terminology.

Comment: Note that the example I gave works: K is compact for the new topology if and only if is closed for the new topology and bounded for the standard metric of R.